# Intrinsicness of Hodge-theoretic properties of Galois representations in a general reductive group

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, galois-theory, galois-representations, hodge-theory

In [the paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1009.0785) *"The conjectural connections between automorphic representations and Galois representations"* by Buzzard and Gee, it is said

> "We say that
>   $\rho$ is crystalline/de Rham/Hodge–Tate if for some (and **hence any**) faithful representation $H \rightarrow GL_N$ over $\mathbb{Q}_p$
>   , the resulting $N$-dimensional Galois representation
>   is crystalline/de Rham/Hodge–Tate."

Here $\rho$ is a homomorphism from the absolute Galois group of a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ to a reductive group $H$ (defined over some algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}_p$). How to prove the "hence any" claim?

Second question: given that the definition does not depend on this choice anyway, is there a way to give a definition not involving this choice (or is there a natural choice here)?

Answer (score 3):

If $H$ is reductive, any irreducible representation of $H$ is a summand of a tensor product of copies of any particular faithful representation and its dual. So it suffices to know these Hodge-theoretic properties are preserved by tensor product and summands. I think these facts can be checked explicitly from the period ring.

To see this claim about representations of reductive group, we take an arbitrary irreducible representation, view its matrix coefficients as functions on the group, thus as polynomials in the coordinates of the embedding into $GL_n$ given by the fixed faithful representation. Whatever the degree of these polynomials is tells you which tensor power you need to take to see your chosen irreducible representation as a subquotient. Then the reductive hypothesis makes it a summand.

Comment: I have the intuition that none of the properties of the period ring matter for this, you just need to know the form of the mysterious functor (i.e. "take the Galois invariants of the tensor product with some random ring"). Is that a correct intuition?

Comment: @kartop_man I think you want to know that the dim of the Galois invariants is always at most the dim of the representation. Then it follows that dim Galois invariants = dim representation is closed under tensor products and summands. For the dual, I think we need a little more information.